# Rename iOS app in iTunes Connect - "name will be reviewed"

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I'm creating a new release of an iOS app in iTunes Connect.

The release has been reviewed and approved by Apple.

However, on the App Information page the following is stated: "The name will be reviewed before it is made available on the App Store."

Does this mean that, for this release, there will be an extra delay after I click "Release this version"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be an additional delay more than the time it usually takes for your app to be reviewed. The message is simply to indicate that your name change must be reviewed at all (so it may not get approved), not to indicate any additional time penalty for review.

Comment: Thanks! After asking other people experienced in app renames too, it seems this is the definitive answer.

Comment: Though it takes a while for the App Store search index to be updated, so even after the renamed app is available for update and download (if you search for the original name), it won't be searchable for several more hours. 5 hours in our case.